# The pop up requestApplicationPermission userDiscoverability doesn't appear

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I would like to get user information via icloud, but when I test both the simulator and the device the pop up requestApplicationPermission userDiscoverability does not appear.

```
func requestPermission() {
    CKContainer.default().requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability) { [weak self] returnedStatus, returnedError in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if returnedStatus == .granted {
                self?.permissionStatus = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are any other operations on the container working?

Comment: yes, all the other operation are working

Comment: Ah, I see in the docs that it only works once. After that this call returns the previously returned value. I put your code in my app and it just returns granted without asking me.

Comment: in my app returns not granted, do you have any idea what the problem could be for the pop up not appearing?